# Prevent the check-in of files to TFS without a code review

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, checkin, tfs-code-review

Can I block the possibility of check in files to TFS in case the code review is not successful?

Comment: Hey mate you've gone all chameleon question on me. Can we revert to your one liner and you can ask the others as different questions? Thanks

Comment: If possible, move to the vNext with GIT workflow, where this is completely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in TFS Team Explorer go to the Project > Settings > Team Project > Source Control and Add a field called Code Reviewer and make it required.

[image]

Comment: Can I enable this option only on the level of the project or solution?

Comment: It's repository wide, if you have one solution per repository then it will work at a solution level, I doubt you'd want projects per repository.

Comment: This option only enforces that a note from a field "Code Reviewer" is populated with text in TFS, it does not enforce that a code review has been associated/requested, and then passed before the submission completes ( I just tried it with TFS 2017)

Comment: @CJBS this is the way TFS worked, personally I thought it was great if followed properly. These days there's too much compliance and governance shoved in our faces. You go to check in & a  load of crappy things happen, oh I didn't use a defined branch Prefix, oh its failing me bc I didn't include the JIRA in the comment, oh Jim Blogs the only person who can review is on Hols, oh the prick Timmy wont approve my PR and he keeps adding pointless comments that dont relate.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Completely agree. My comment is regarding the assertion that this approach blocks code reviews, which it doesn't (it only enforces a comment).